# Linkind date with many folders

Tags: python, sql, r, csv, merge

I have a CSV folder containing the [date](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Cac4ckrb) (from 7/8/2005 to  9/27/2013).
So the csv contains only one column with the date

I have 50 other folders containing the same structure.
The columns are :

1. **Date** [structure of the date is the same as my date.csv ]
2. Open
3. High
4. Low
5. **Close**
6. Volume
7. Adj. Close
8. **Symbol**

*I've bolded the columns I'm interested in to get my final output*

I give 2 files of those folders :

1. [AI.PA.csv](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uqJkCDe5)
2. [ALV.DE.csv](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=XBGhjiHm)

My aim (question) is to get a final new file with x column :

- Date (same structure date as date.csv)
- Symbol AI.PA
- Symbol AI.DE
- Symbol of all the other files I have

So the column should contain the symbol as column header and the closing price if there is a closing price for the ad hoc date. And if tehre is no closing price it should contain nothing.

I really don't know how to solve the issue. I'm open to solve my issue with any "open source" solution (ideally SQL, Python, R)

[image]

Comment: This is a Q&A site, and you posed no question. The problem is too specific to have a generic "open source solution" - what have you tried?

Comment: @goncalopp Maybe I did not explained correctly what I wanted to do. By Open Source I just wanted to explain that I want to solve my issue with something that is free. I don't want to pay a software to solve my issue. And I asked a question (cf. : "My aim is to get a final new file...")

Comment: I guess what I meant is that while this can be easily solved using any general programming language, no language will help you by itself. You'll need to ask *specific* questions. Otherwise the answer would be "learn about string processing and file I/O" - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Hum then is there any language who is easier than the other to do that?

Comment: If you don't know any language yet, my personal opinion is that R may be easier for this type of work. [Here's a explanation for reading CSV files into memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391880/how-to-get-a-csv-file-into-r)

Comment: Ok thanks I will have a look. Actually I know R and Python as programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acutally I just solve my issue by using a simple Pivot table on Excel