# Add column to label U.S. states by their U.S. Census region

Tags: r

I have data containing email addresses and U.S. states, and I want to create a column labeling the U.S. Census region each state is in. In SQL, I've done this through case statements, but in R what's the best way?

Sample Data:

```
df <- data.frame(emails=c("xyz@gmail.com","abc@hotmail.com","bba@gmai.com","so121@gamil.com","ad@yahoo.com"), states=c("NV","CA","UT","AZ","IA"))
```

The sample data look like this:

```
emails        states
xyz@gmail.com    NV      
abc@hotmail.com  CA      
bba@gmai.com     UT       
so121@gamil.com  AZ       
ad@yahoo.com     IA
```

I want the result to be:

```
emails           states  regions
xyz@gmail.com    NV      West
abc@hotmail.com  CA      West
bba@gmai.com     UT      West
so121@gamil.com  AZ      West
ad@yahoo.com     IA      Midwest
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `split(df1$states, df1$regions)`  or if you need a separate column, then with `dcast` i.e. `library(data.table); dcast(setDT(df1), rowid(regions)~regions, value.var = "states")`

Comment: @akrun..Thanku for giving a start..But I have a quick question.. How i will group these states into regions? AS this region column is the output i want

Comment: I think the best option would be to have a `list` using `split` as mentioned above in my comments

Comment: @sim - akrun mentions some good options too. In order for us to help the most, would you mind giving a description, or better yet a sample, of what you'd like the output to be in your question?

Comment: @akrun..can u please explain more? list?

Comment: @RyanRunge the output of my question is region column.. I only have email and states available..so the very first step i want to is to group these states in regions s shown in sample  and then put this all in a third column named region..Hope this explanation will help you getting me solution

Comment: @sim - I see. That's a very different question. First, are you using the region names defined by the U.S. census; [see here](https://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/maps-data/maps/reference/us_regdiv.pdf). Or how? Second, are your states all abbreviated like in the sample above, with some lower case, some upper case?

Comment: @Ryan Runge..Yes region names are as defined by U.S census..and all the state names are in upper case..

Comment: @sim - okay good, I can work on that then. In the meantime, please adjust the question with a few of those details to help the SO community.

Comment: @RyanRunge..sure Thanks..

Comment: You can also use the `sqldf` package and do it however you did it before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hard part as usual is collecting the data first, but I happened to have it archived from the [US Census](https://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/maps-data/maps/reference/us_regdiv.pdf). So run the following lines of code *after* running the "State/Region Data" section below:

```
df <- data.frame(emails=c("xyz@gmail.com","abc@hotmail.com","bba@gmai.com",
                          "so121@gamil.com","ad@yahoo.com"),
                 states=c("NV","CA","UT","AZ","IA"))

df$regions <- sapply(df$states, 
                 function(x) names(region.list)[grep(x,region.list)])

#Then write to desktop, for example, with:
write.csv(df,"~/Desktop/nameHere.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

Output:

```
           emails states regions
1   xyz@gmail.com     NV    West
2 abc@hotmail.com     CA    West
3    bba@gmai.com     UT    West
4 so121@gamil.com     AZ    West
5    ad@yahoo.com     IA Midwest
```

State/Region Data:

```
NE.name <- c("Connecticut","Maine","Massachusetts","New Hampshire",
             "Rhode Island","Vermont","New Jersey","New York",
             "Pennsylvania")
NE.abrv <- c("CT","ME","MA","NH","RI","VT","NJ","NY","PA")
NE.ref <- c(NE.name,NE.abrv)

MW.name <- c("Indiana","Illinois","Michigan","Ohio","Wisconsin",
             "Iowa","Kansas","Minnesota","Missouri","Nebraska",
             "North Dakota","South Dakota")
MW.abrv <- c("IN","IL","MI","OH","WI","IA","KS","MN","MO","NE",
             "ND","SD")
MW.ref <- c(MW.name,MW.abrv)

S.name <- c("Delaware","District of Columbia","Florida","Georgia",
            "Maryland","North Carolina","South Carolina","Virginia",
            "West Virginia","Alabama","Kentucky","Mississippi",
            "Tennessee","Arkansas","Louisiana","Oklahoma","Texas")
S.abrv <- c("DE","DC","FL","GA","MD","NC","SC","VA","WV","AL",
            "KY","MS","TN","AR","LA","OK","TX")
S.ref <- c(S.name,S.abrv)

W.name <- c("Arizona","Colorado","Idaho","New Mexico","Montana",
            "Utah","Nevada","Wyoming","Alaska","California",
            "Hawaii","Oregon","Washington")
W.abrv <- c("AZ","CO","ID","NM","MT","UT","NV","WY","AK","CA",
            "HI","OR","WA")
W.ref <- c(W.name,W.abrv)

region.list <- list(
  Northeast=NE.ref,
  Midwest=MW.ref,
  South=S.ref,
  West=W.ref)
```

Comment: ..In my data i have thousand of emails.so in the start where u mentioned emails how will i enter those all emails??

Comment: @sim - What format is your data in? Is it a text file, a CSV? Please search around for pages like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391880/how-to-get-a-csv-file-into-r) on read.csv() in order to "read in" your data to R. You don't have to manually enter them. The sample data above is just to demo my answer.

Comment: ..My data is in CSV file

Comment: Okay good. Did you get something to work? Something like "df <- read.csv('yourData.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')" ? If the above answer solves your question, please consider voting it as a solution so that the community knows and people with a similar question in the future can more quickly find the answer.

Comment: ..sorry for late reply..I implemented it and it is working right but when i write it back to desktop gets this error Error in write.table(US, "C:\\Users\\cool\\Desktop\\test merge\\US.csv",  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'

Comment: Try write.csv(), and see my edit above that shows how.

Comment: To reproducibly use the code / information here, you could wrap the "State / Region" data section into a function `load_state_region_data()` and call it.