# Transforming csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I'm quite new in R. So. could you please tell me how to transform ordinary rows and columns into dataframe?

For example, I have data in such way:

```
Id, gender
1   1
2   0
3   1
4   0
5   0
```

but actually that is not a dataframe with rows and columns, just note without being as a table.

Thank you.

Comment: google "read csv file in R" i.e.: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-import

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a .csv file into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391880/how-to-get-a-csv-file-into-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is simply a text file and only header row has commas, the file can be read with `read.table()`. Use the `skip=` and `col.names=` arguments to correct the heading row.

```
rawData <- "Id, gender
1   1
2   0
3   1
4   0
5   0"

aDataFrame <- read.table(textConnection(rawData),header=FALSE,col.names=c("Id","gender"),skip=1)

aDataFrame
```

...and the output:

```
> aDataFrame
  Id gender
1  1      1
2  2      0
3  3      1
4  4      0
5  5      0
>
```