# In R from a csv file get rows from a column which contain more then 2 characters

Tags: r, character, dimensions

I have a csv file from which I have to get rows which have more then 2 characters from a specific coloumn. My csv file look like this

```
"Name" "Age" "ID"     "RefID"
"ABC"  "12"  "Abccc"  "xyzw"
"AAA"  "14"  "A"      "X"
"BBB"  "18"  "DEfff"  "dfg"
"CCY"  "10"  "F"      "XY"
"CCZ"  "20"  "R"      "XYC"
```

So from column 3 and 4 I have take rows which have >= two characters.

I tried following way

```
data = read.table(file ='res.csv', header = T)
dat2 = as.character(data[,3])
ind = dat2[(which(nchar(dat2) >=2)),]
```

But its giving me error and I am not able to find out how can I proceed with both cols at once. 
My result should be like below

```
"Name" "Age" "ID"     "RefID"
"ABC"  "12"  "Abccc"  "xyzw"
"BBB"  "18"  "DEfff"  "dfg"
"CCY"  "10"  "F"      "XY"
"CCZ"  "20"  "R"      "XYC"
```

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: if you want to load your data in variables look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391880/how-to-get-a-csv-file-into-r

Comment: @RonakShah yes still i need those rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can avoid multiple steps, i.e. conversion to `character` class by specifying `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `read.table` to avoid converting the character columns to `factor` class.  Then, get the number of characters of the third column with `nchar` and create the logical condition by comparing if it is greater than or equal to 2

```
data[nchar(data[,3])>=2,]
#   Name Age    ID RefID
#1  ABC  12 Abccc  xyzw
#3  BBB  18 DEfff   dfg
```

For multiple columns, use `&`

```
data[nchar(data[,3])>=2 & data[,4] >=2,]
```

But, it would become a bit difficult when there are 100s of columns.  For this purpose, we loop through the columns of interest, do the comparison and `Reduce` it to a single logical `vector`

```
data[Reduce(`&`, lapply(data[3:4], function(x) nchar(x) >=2)),]
#  Name Age    ID RefID
#1  ABC  12 Abccc  xyzw
#3  BBB  18 DEfff   dfg
```

If the condition needs to be TRUE for `any` of the columns, then change the `&` to `|` in the `Reduce`

```
data[Reduce(`|`, lapply(data[3:4], function(x) nchar(x) >=2)),]
#   Name Age    ID RefID
#1  ABC  12 Abccc  xyzw
#3  BBB  18 DEfff   dfg
#4  CCY  10     F    XY
#5  CCZ  20     R   XYC
```

#### data

```
data <- read.table(file ='res.csv', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: its giving me error: nchar()' requires a character vector.

Comment: @KritikaRajain  As I mentioned in the post, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while reading.  Updated the `data` step

Comment: Thanks a lot but one more thing my result should have rows if any one cols have character >=2

Comment: @KritikaRajain  Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on data.table. `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is the default in `data.table::fread`.

```
require(data.table)

x= 
fread('"Name" "Age" "ID"     "RefID"
"ABC"  "12"  "Abccc"  "xyzw"
"AAA"  "14"  "A"      "X"
"BBB"  "18"  "DEfff"  "dfg"
"CCY"  "10"  "F"      "XY"
"CCZ"  "20"  "R"      "XYC"')

x[nchar(ID)>2 | nchar(RefID)>2]

   Name Age    ID RefID
1:  ABC  12 Abccc  xyzw
2:  BBB  18 DEfff   dfg
```

For the `OR` (`|`) case you could also melt by Name and Age and subset based on nchar. 
here is a one-liner:

```
z = melt(x, id.vars = c('Name', 'Age'))[nchar(value) > 2 ]
z 
 Name Age variable value
1:  ABC  12       ID Abccc
2:  BBB  18       ID DEfff
3:  ABC  12    RefID  xyzw
4:  BBB  18    RefID   dfg
5:  CCZ  20    RefID   XYC
```